# Does Snapping work for lines as well as polygons?

Tags: qgis, line, snapping

I can get snapping working with polygons to form a set with full coverage but I can't get it to work with lines.   What I want to do is have the end of one line segment snap to the end of another.  I.e the two ends have the same geometry.

In my research nearly all the references to snapping involve polygons not lines.

For the record the big picture is that I have a set of line segments representing a network of tracks.  The same line segments also form the boundaries of polygons.  Individual tracks often have more than one segment and I need to have end points snapped so I can generate layers with polygons and tracks that are a single feature automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is Yes, sorry for this simplistic reply.

It may be difficult to see the snapping points in the figure below, but snapping **Line-to-Line** (snapping vertices of new line to existing line) works.

It is also possible to snap polygon (black polygon below) vertices to existing line nodes (**Polygon-to-Line** snapping) and vice versa (line-to-polygon).

*Avoid intersections* function is not available to lines, though.

[image]

Comment: It was a yes, no sort of question ;)   I needed to know if I was on the right track or down a rabbit hole.  Thank you for the screen shot!  I knew about the setting in the preferences but that was clearly different.  Googling "snapping options"  pointed me to Snapping options in the settings menu.   That's what I was missing.

Comment: Ah, great. Glad to know you worked it out so quickly :)